# React Native Shadow Styles not working on View Component

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if anyone knew anyway to make the shadow styles on a react native view component work. I scavenged all of the web and could not find any solutions. My code is shown below:

```
//Stylesheet code:
...
  profileImage: {
      width: 170,
      height: 170,
      overflow: "hidden",
      marginLeft: (Dimensions.get('window').width/2) - 85,
      marginTop: 30,
      borderRadius: 170,
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 5
  },
...
//View component:
<View style={styles.profileImage}>
      <Image source={require("../assets/images/temporaryProfilePicture.jpg")} style={styles.image} resizeMode="cover"></Image>
</View>
...
```

Any and all help would be largely appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to add `backgroundColor: '#ffffff'` to `profileImage` style.

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ive achieved with your code and link to it :[expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/ryG89aXfL) :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Dimensions ,Image} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Image  source={{uri:'https://source.unsplash.com/random'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
     width: 170,
      height: 170,
      overflow: "hidden",
      marginLeft: (Dimensions.get('window').width/2) - 85,
      marginTop: 30,
      borderRadius: 170,
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.8,
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 5
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: This code works for android, but it does not work for IOS. For android, there was never this bug, but it was just made visible in IOS. Do you have any solution for IOS?